# How to execute dotnet core restore and publish commands in Gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: batch-file, yaml, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've got a project where we have a quickpublish.cmd file that contains the following code:

```
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" restore
::"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build

"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" publish "./src/Web/Web.csproj" --output "../../../quickpublish/Web" --configuration release
::"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test "./tests/Tests.Web/Tests.Web.csproj"
::"D:\Apps\nodejs\node.exe" npm install
```

I am unfamiliar with what this language/syntax is. all the same, I am tasked with setting up Continuous Integration with Gitlab, and I'm equally uncertain what the the equivalent yaml should look like.

How can I execute `dotnet restore` and `dotnet publish` within Gitlab